# Accounting Data Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

i want to generate Excel file using `c#`. Am using `NPOI XSSFWorkbook` class. while printing a decimal value in Excel sheet i want to give it Accounting formatting.

For Example my data should look like `$35.00`. But am not able to achieve it using XSSFWorkbook class. i have already tried
`CellStyle.DataFormat = _workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("#,##0");`

Comment: please check the answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283268/why-npoi-created-cell-drop-down-list-always-split-by-comma/44955100#44955100 link. if formatting doesn't work, you can replace format pattern with the pattern provided by shrikant.

Answer (score 0):

Try first set the style for your cell and then change it Format attribute, but with custom format like this:

```
IDataFormat dataFormatCustom = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
cell.CellStyle = styles["cell"]; 
cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)");
```

May be this will work i am not sure.

Comment: Tried that even am able to get the data in currency format but not in accounting format.